# I want to print many SpliPanes, each SplitPane on a new page.

Tags: printing, javafx

I have a ArrayList with many SplitPanes.
Each SplitPane i like to print to a new page.
It don't works.

```
@FXML
private void handlePrint(ActionEvent event) {
    for (Object split : listSplitPanes) {
        printModul.print((Node) split);
    }


public void print(final Node node) {
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
    PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
    double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
    double scaleY = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight() / node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
    node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scaleX, scaleY));

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null) {
        if (job.showPrintDialog(primaryStage.getOwner())) {
            boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, node);
            if (success) {
                job.endJob();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error. It prints the first SplitPane perfect, each other with empty pages.

Have someone a idea?

Thank you
Gerhard Laib

Answer (score -1):

@Gerhard Laib
You job is complete and the boolean success is true so end of printing job.endJob
I would try to write some test to print the other nodes that keeps the print job alive. sorry no code as I am trying the same thing with a GridPane to print multiple pages without much luck. Who ever writes tutorials for JavaFX I guess never thought about printing and a desktop application